# How to create own html report without using TestNg and Junit frameworks?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to create own html report without using TestNg and Junit frameworks ?
For each and every step i want to take screenshots by using take screenshot syntax i can but only for single step it is working.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement below testNg interface to implement your ownHTML Report.

IReporter

otherwise you can use below link to get reports code.

https://github.com/allure-framework

Comment: that is not salable when you have more tests automated in your project. even IReporter implemented class you will do similar way but will be more generic to entire automation project

Comment: Ok..I want to take screenshot for all the steps how can i take i have to add loop or is there any other process

Comment: in POM(page object model), for every page navigation take the screen shot on loading and on finishing , that will help you for debugging purpose in test automation.
taking screen shot for every step is not feasible solution , because it require lot of memory and slowdown the test run

Comment: So..your saying like for every page navigation..I have to add the syntax r8..iam i correct